# How can I add all languages in tesseract OCR using Tika config?

Tags: java, tesseract, apache-tika

I have a Tika + Tesseract connection in my project.

I add tesseract in Tika:

```
//other objects
AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
ParseContext pc = new ParseContext(); 
Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
Tika tika = new Tika();
BodyContentHandler ch = new BodyContentHandler(-1); 
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("src/main/resources/sample.txt"));

//init
TesseractOCRConfig tesserConfig = new TesseractOCRConfig();
tesserConfig.setTesseractPath("E:\\Program Files\\tesseractOCR");
tesserConfig.setTessdataPath("E:\\Program Files\\tesseractOCR\\tessdata");
tesserConfig.setImageMagickPath("E:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-7.1.0-Q16-HDRI");   

//add
pc.set(TesseractOCRConfig.class, tesserConfig);

//using
parser.parse(is, ch, metadata, pc);
```

To add languages inside tesseract, you need to call the method and pass the name of the language:

```
tesserConfig.setLanguage("NameOfLang");
```

The given name is the crossed name of the language, for example, if I want to use English, I use such a call:

```
tesserConfig.setLanguage("eng");
```

In theory, this name is consistent with the necessary files in the TesseractOCR\tessdata folder.
In our case: eng - eng.traineddata.

---

I know that to use multiple languages, you need to pass them as a parameter to the setLanguage method.

For example, to use 3 languages: English, German and Japanese, you need to call this method:

```
tesserConfig.setLanguage("eng+deu+jpn");
```

---

But if I don't know the language I need in advance, or if I can't even roughly pick up a list of several specific languages, then it turns out I need to add all the languages at once.

So far, it has not been possible to find a way to add all languages inside tesseract. If you do not use the setLanguage method, then only one language will be used by default, English.

Therefore, hence the question is there a way to add all available languages inside tesseract? Maybe there is an approach that I haven't found yet, please tell me.

At the moment, I see this solution: all the necessary languages (which means all how many there are, 100 or 130 available languages) will need to be passed to setLanguage, and it should look something like this:

```
tesserConfig.setLanguage("LANG(1)+LANG(2)+LANG(3)+...+LANG(N)");
```

Please tell me, maybe there is a better way than this, I haven't found anything better for myself yet.

Comment: tesseract documentation has a list of supported languages: https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/Data-Files-in-different-versions.html - based on which tesseract version is used you could build your language string from the table on that site.

Comment: My question was if it is possible to load all available languages ​​into a string in an alternative way. And not what I described or not.

Comment: But as I understand it, you need to make all the languages ​​​​in only by listing the necessary languages.